Can we have second level of customization for aspx screen in acumatica In Existing tab of First customization
I have done one customization in Acumatica Inventory screen, I have added one tab.
In second customization I want to add two more field in Tab section which I have Customized in First customization.
Is My second Customization I could not see First customization tab....How Can  I add new fields.
Is Any to add only new Field in aspx page or i need to add whole tab section alongs with new fields

The only option currently is to do that second part of the customization in the first package. The second customization option will work only with new screens added by the first customization. The changes added by the first package are kind of "ignored" in the second customization's layout editor.
